# PHP - can't compare two "Strings" (?)

Tags: php, string, comparison

So this is my code:

```
   $handle = @fopen("csgo_english.txt", "r"); //read line one by one


                $paintkitsStarted = false;
                while (!feof($handle)) // Start looping until there is no line anymore.
                 {
                    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.

                     $convertedBuffer = $buffer;
                        echo $convertedBuffer;

                     if($convertedBuffer == "// Paint Kits "){
                         $paintkitsStarted = true;
                         echo "Paintkit Line found! <br>";
                     }
                     if($convertedBuffer == "// END CRATE_COMMUNITY_10 "){
                        $paintkitsStarted = false;
                         echo "Paintkits ending here! <br>";
                     }
                     if($paintkitsStarted == true){
                         echo $buffer . "<br>";
                     }
```

I'm trying to read the .txt-File (which works great) and then comparing a line of it with a string. I already tried casting it to a string using:

```
$convertedBuffer = "$buffer";
```

and

```
$convertedBuffer = (string)$buffer;
```

as well as

```
$convertedBuffer = $buffer . "";
```

I don't know why this isn't working as it should, because I actually took the string I needed by copying it from the output using `echo $buffer` which should work.

If anyone has Ideas, I would be grateful to hear them :)

Comment: sure to compare use == you are using only one =, Also http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: `var_dump($convertedBuffer)`

Comment: @volkinc I think you should get some glasses ... all my if's are made with two equals ;)

Comment: @u_mulder, thanks but it says it's a string .. well then the fault is on my side :)

Comment: Check for some spaces or maybe tabs in you string

Comment: Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline **(which is included in the return value)**. Maybe `trim($buffer)` and get rid of the trailing space in your double-quoted strings.

Comment: The line returned by `fgets()` ends with a newline. The strings you're comparing with don't.

Comment: @njoye True my bad, First try trim($buffer). Can you give en example of $buffer value? and also if you trim the $buffer, delete blank space at the end of the string you compare with

Comment: You can also sanitize the buffer by $buffer = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z_\s\/]+/", "", $buffer);

Comment: `echo` is a very bad choice for debugging, for several reasons. Try something sane like `var_dump`.

Comment: I now trimmed the buffer and also removed the space at the end of my comparison string. output looks like this (at least this is what i am looking for, after trimming it: `string(25) "// Paint Kits"` used `var_dump()` on this one.) trimming it still doesn't get it even though they seem to be the same!

Comment: Other outputs are looking like this (randomly chosen): `string(86) " "PaintKit_so_sand_Tag" "Sand Dune" "`, `string(4) " "` or `string(179) ""PaintKit_cu_broken_path_famas" "It has been custom-painted with broken ribbon trails.""`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath ok, let's assume that: `// Paint Kits` (which is the comparison string) and `// Paint Kits` (the original string, i even copied that out for you ;) ) are not the same ... why isn't it working then ?!

Comment: You want to tell me i'm not able to copy and paste a string or what ? ... yeah sure ...

Comment: ..... well the quotes won't make a difference because they are exactly the same strings (which makes me wonder, which is why i asked this question)... closing now, got enough of this

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so I still don't know what the problem was. But something probably was wrong with the file, because I just copied the content of the original into a second one and after doing that and trying it with the second one, it worked. Don't ask me why ...

Comment: Have you checked the file encoding?

UTF-8 has two initial bytes to "warn" it's encoded in UTF-8, and those bytes won't be shown in any "echo" output, but will make any comparison to another string without those bytes fail. That's probably true for other text file encodings too.

Comment: BOM is the word. That's how the "header bytes" are called. Each encoding allows for different characters. I use mostly UTF-8, as has wider characters support than the basic ANSI which is only really useful for English. Other encodings allows to input Japanese text, and wide character encodings (2 or more bytes for character) allows to input any character in the same file.